# If statment using array as multiple conditions

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I need to have an array to use as conditions like so

```
$array = array(
 $a => '1',
 $b => '3',
);

if($array){
 echo 'OK';
}
```

If $a equals 1 or $b equals to 3 than - ok.
I remember it's possible and i have done it before but i can't remeber how to do it and i can't find it on Google.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Use the code below

```
<?php
$array = array(
 $a => '1',
 $b => '3',
);

if($array[$a]==1 || $array[$b]==3){
 echo 'OK';
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: no, i don't need to check the array, i need to use the array as a condition. Without "or" / "||".

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean in_array() ?

```
if(in_array('1',$array)){
    echo 'OK';
}
```

or do u mean to check if the array is empty?

```
if(!empty($array)){
    echo 'OK';
}
```

if those don't answer your question please elaborate more.